# Starting WPF application with elevated privileges takes a long time as a normal user

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, uac

I have a .Net 4.5.2 WPF application that requires administrator privileges. The application has a manifest file that states the application should run with highest privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The application works fine when I start it (in Windows 7 (this cannot be upgraded)) and I get a UAC prompt when I start the application.

However, the application takes a long time to start when logged on as a normal user (some times up to 30 seconds), even if the user is part of the Administrators group. When starting while logged on as the proper administrator user it starts immediately.

I've also tried starting it from Task Scheduler as the administrator user, but then the GUI isn't displayed. This was only done for testing purposes and would not be good for a final solution.

Why is it so slow as a normal user, and what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Had the same issue. but it did not take 30 seconds. It was more like 15 to 20 seconds. But my conditions matched the same as yours.

Comment: what happens when you rightclick your application and select 'Run as administrator'? Is it the same or faster? If it's just as slow - what happens when you try to open another program using the same method ('Run as administrator')? If it's also slow, this could be an issue with the network/domain server.